# How does the ViewModel constructor get the required interfaces?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, viewmodel

My question based on [InventorySampleApp](https://github.com/microsoft/InventorySample) by Microsoft.

The `ServiceLocator` contains method `Configure()` that register Services and ViewModels. With method `GetService<T>()` we can get it. For example, `ProductView.cs`:

```
ViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetService<ProductDetailsViewModel>();
```

Each `*ViewModel` contains constructor with interface, for example:

```
public ProductDetailsViewModel(IProductService productService, IFilePickerService filePickerService, ICommonServices commonServices)
```

I can't understand the *magiс* that ViewModel uses to get such interfaces into its constructor. So there are no lines like this:

```
... = new ProductDetailsViewModel(productService, filePickerService, commonServices)
```

How does the ViewModel constructor get the required interfaces?

**ServiceLocator**

```
public class ServiceLocator : IDisposable
{
    static private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, ServiceLocator> _serviceLocators = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ServiceLocator>();

    static private ServiceProvider _rootServiceProvider = null;

    static public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IDataServiceFactory, DataServiceFactory>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILookupTables, LookupTables>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IOrderService, OrderService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IOrderItemService, OrderItemService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IProductService, ProductService>();

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMessageService, MessageService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILogService, LogService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IDialogService, DialogService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IFilePickerService, FilePickerService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILoginService, LoginService>();

        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IContextService, ContextService>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<ICommonServices, CommonServices>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<LoginViewModel>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ShellViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<MainShellViewModel>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<DashboardViewModel>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<CustomersViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<CustomerDetailsViewModel>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<OrdersViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<OrderDetailsViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<OrderDetailsWithItemsViewModel>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<OrderItemsViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<OrderItemDetailsViewModel>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ProductsViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ProductDetailsViewModel>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<AppLogsViewModel>();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<SettingsViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ValidateConnectionViewModel>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<CreateDatabaseViewModel>();

        _rootServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    static public ServiceLocator Current
    {
        get
        {
            int currentViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            return _serviceLocators.GetOrAdd(currentViewId, key => new ServiceLocator());
        }
    }

    static public void DisposeCurrent()
    {
        int currentViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        if (_serviceLocators.TryRemove(currentViewId, out ServiceLocator current))
        {
            current.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private IServiceScope _serviceScope = null;

    private ServiceLocator()
    {
        _serviceScope = _rootServiceProvider.CreateScope();
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return GetService<T>(true);
    }

    public T GetService<T>(bool isRequired)
    {
        if (isRequired)
        {
            return _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
        }
        return _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
    }

    #region Dispose
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_serviceScope != null)
            {
                _serviceScope.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: There is no magic, it's done via constructor injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using dependency injection, the instantiation of objects is moved to a component called *Dependency Injection (DI) Container* or *Inverse of Control (IoC) Container*. This component has some kind of registry that contains all known services that can be instantiated. In your example, the `serviceCollection` is that registry.

Now, whenever a component `A` needs an instance from the registry, there are two different options:

1. Directly ask the container for an instance, e. g. `ServiceLocator.Current.GetService<ProductDetailsViewModel>()`. This is known as the *Service Locator Pattern* (I'd recommend to forget this immediately).
2. Rather than asking the container directly, request the dependency via constructor of `A` (e. g. `public A(ProductDetailsViewModel viewModel)`).

The second approach can be pushed more and more upwards until the top of the application hierarchy is reached - the so called `composition root`.

Anyways, in both ways, the container uses the mechanism of [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). It is a way of retrieving metadata of classes, methods, properties, constructors, etc. Whenever the container is asked for a certain type (e. g. `ProductDetailsViewModel`), he uses reflection to get information about its constructor.
Once the constructor is resolved, its dependencies are known as well (`IProductService`, `IFilePickerService`, `ICommonServices`). Since these dependencies are registered within the container (remember the `serviceCollection`), instances can be created.
This goes on and on until there are no more dependencies and the container can start instantiating and composing all the objects. Finally, there is an instance of `ProductDetailsViewModel`.
If there is one dependency within the construction chain that is unknown to the container, the instantiation fails.

So basically, the process of instantiation is moved away from your code into the DI container.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the `GetService` method calls into [ServiceProvider.GetService](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceprovider.getservice). This is a library method that takes care of things for you. Underneath the covers, it uses *reflection* to examine the constructor of the type you request.

For example, when you request a `ProductDetailsViewModel`, the `ServiceLocator` can see that it needs object of the types `IProductService`, `IFilePickerService`, `ICommonServices`.

It then looks into its registry of services. For example, the line

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IProductService, ProductService>();
```

registers the concrete type `ProductService` against the interface `IProductService`, so whenever the `ServiceLocator` needs to create an `IProductService` object, it'll use a `ProductService` object.

This process is called **auto-wiring** and is described in more details in chapter 12 of Steven van Deursen's and my [book about Dependency Injection](https://amzn.to/2TE8tJx).

> I can't understand the *magiс* that ViewModel uses to get such interfaces into its constructor.

Indeed, do yourself the favour and learn [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) instead of relying on opaque libraries that you don't feel comfortable with.

I've never seen that example code base before, but from the examples posted here, it looks like it's filled with code smells and anti-patterns.

Comment: May you help with [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60333996/differences-and-similarities-between-viewmodellocator-servicelocator-dependen)?