# Differences and similarities between: ViewModelLocator, ServiceLocator, Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm confused about the patterns: `ViewModelLocator`, `ServiceLocator`, `Dependency Injection`.

The latest conclusion are as follows:

`ViewModelLocator`. The place to connect `View` and `ViewModel`.

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SettingViewModel>();
}

public MainViewModel MainViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
public SettingViewModel SettingViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<SettingViewModel>();

// View
private MainViewModel ViewModel => ViewModelLocator.Current.MainViewModel;
```

*Dependency Injection*. A set of principles for weak connections. Often through the constructor.

```
private readonly INavigationService _navigation;

public ShellViewModel(INavigationService navigation)
{
    _navigation = navigation;
}
```

`ServiceLocator`. What is it? The same as `ViewModelLocator`, but considered by many to be an anti-pattern? It turns out `ViewModelLocator` is also bad. But how then to connected `View` and `ViewModel`? `ServiceLocator` only needs to store Services? As you understand, all the confusion is from `ServiceLocator`.

Could you explain the differences and similarities between these elements? To finally uniquely identify and use them correctly. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [recently asked a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60318881/126014), and from it I infer that `ViewModelLocator` etc. originate from the sample code base you linked to there. From what I gather from the code examples shown so far, it doesn't look like that code base is the best example of using Dependency Injection.

Thus, any question that involves explaining the 'patterns' in that code base should be met by the response [mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)).

The question implies a false premise. The premise is that there's something to be learned from that code base. That may not be the case.

Service Locator isn't a pattern; [it's an anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern). (Most people seem to agree with me, and so far no-one has been able to produce a compelling counter-argument.)

Dependency Injection isn't a pattern; it's *a set of* design principles and (several) patterns. That's what we've attempted to describe in [our book](https://blog.ploeh.dk/dippp).

> how then to connected `View` and `ViewModel`?

The best explanation of the MVVM pattern is still, I believe, [Josh Smith's original article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern). If you want to see a complete code example that combines MVVM and Dependency Injection, it's available with [the first edition of Dependency Injection in .NET](http://amzn.to/12p90MG) (which is also included as a free e-book with the new edition).

> `ServiceLocator` only needs to store Services?

No, there should be no Service Locator at all. That's an example of what I mean. It seems that that code base isn't a good way to learn about Dependency Injection. It generates more confusion than insight.

Comment: May you read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/february/mvvm-ioc-containers-and-mvvm)? What do you think about ViewModelLocator based on article?

Comment: @Viewed From skimming that article, it looks as though the `ViewModelLocator` itself [isn't a Service Locator, but rather an Abstract Factory](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryorServiceLocator). There's nothing wrong with that in itself, but internally it uses a Service Locator, so I'd still not consider such code meriting emulation.

Comment: I had a mixed feeling. On the one hand, there are ubiquitous examples (from Microsoft too) and the popular MVVM Light framework. On the other hand, your "war" with Service Locator and links to the article and book. At this point, I come to the conclusion that the problems from ServiceLocator are not for my programming experience. Because this is a choice between working examples for people like me (inexperienced, beginners) and abstraction, thinking about "what if.."with the creation of a "Bicycle" (again, for my experience).

Comment: By the way, I note that ServiceLocator [has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486388/uwp-mvvmlight-replacing-obsolete-servicelocator) from MVVM Light. That is, ViewModelLocator is built only with SimpleIoc. As far as I understand.

Comment: @Viewed Dependency Injection (DI) is, indeed, an intermediary topic. If you're inexperienced, it may not be the best place to start. DI solves problems in the medium and long run. It's not going to help you get things working here and now. If that's your problem, then ignore all of DI, and Service Locator as well. Once, however, you want to address those longer-perspective problems, you want to actually *solve* them, I suppose? If so, you'll need to learn how to do that. https://www.infoq.com/articles/Succeeding-Dependency-Injection